# 690mb memory overhead for openmp program compiled with ifort

Tags: memory, fortran, openmp

I was running some tests using openmp and fortran and came to realize that a binary compiled with ifort 15 (15.0.0 20140723) has 690MB of virtual memory overhead.

My sample program is:

```
program sharedmemtest
  use omp_lib
  implicit none
  integer :: nroot1
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(14,200)
  real(dp),allocatable :: matrix_elementsy(:,:,:,:)

  !$OMP PARALLEL NUM_THREADS(10) SHARED(matrix_elementsy)                                                                                                                           
  nroot1=2

  if (OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() == 0) then
    allocate(matrix_elementsy(nroot1,nroot1,nroot1,nroot1))
    print *, "after allocation"
    read(*,*)
  end if
  !$OMP BARRIER                                                                                                                                                                     

  !$OMP END PARALLEL                                                                                                                                                                
end program
```

running

```
ifort -openmp test_openmp_minimal.f90 && ./a.out
```

shows a memory usage of

```
50694 user    20   0  694m 8516 1340 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.58 a.out
```

in top. Running

```
gfortran -fopenmp test_openmp_minimal.f90 && ./a.out
```

shows a memory usage of

```
50802 user    20   0 36616  956  740 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.98 a.out
```

Where is the 690MB of overhead coming from when compiling with ifort? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in ifort?

For completeness: This is a minimal example taken from a much larger program. I am using gfortran 4.4 (4.4.7 20120313).

I appreciate all comments and ideas.

Comment: Virtual memory does not necessary get mapped. This overhead may be strictly virtual.

Comment: True, but this is nonetheless significant. If you run this program on a computer cluster with a job scheduler (as is the case for this program), I need to reserve extra resources to allow for the virtual memory reservation. On a node with 16 cores that would be 9.6 GB which is considerable (and expensive) overhead.

Comment: What awful scheduler is this?

Comment: torque/moab if its configuration requires the setting of either vmem or pvmem. Or am I mistaken? I have to admit I didn't run tests on this yet, but in the past some jobs of mine have been canceled by violating those limits (for instance if I allocated large arrays). So I am very anxious everytime I see some spurious memory usage. Even if it's just virtual.

Comment: But this particular case with the openmp overhead might be different. Is there a chance that torque/moab counts resources differently than listed by top?

Comment: top is an inaccurate way to measure memory usage. A profiling malloc would be much better. I can write you something with mallinfo if necessary. I don't know what torque uses. Does this system have online docs? I'm familiar with quite a few supercomputer installations in US and Europe...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out mallinfo, I didn't know about this function before. I looked at its man page and it looks interesting. I should be able to call a suitable C routine from Fortran. While looking at the man page I noticed "Information is returned for only the main memory allocation area." What does this limitation mean?

Comment: And yes torque has an online documentation: http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/products/open-source/torque/ http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/6-0-0/help.htm Torque is the resource manager that we use in combination with moab (who is the workload manager)

Comment: And should we move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100482/discussion-between-jeff-and-ftiaronsem).

Comment: I suggest you look a the maps file to see where the memory is being used (cat /proc/pid/maps) where pid is the appropriate pid. That should give you more to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe `top` is reliable here.  I do not see any evidence that the binary created from your test allocates anywhere near that much memory.

Below I have shown the result of generating the binary normally, with the Intel libraries linked statically and with everything linked statically.  The static binary is in the ballpark of 2-3 megabytes.

It is possible that OpenMP thread stacks, which I believe are allocated from the heap, could be the source of the addition virtual memory here.  Can you try this test with `OMP_STACKSIZE=4K`?  I think the default is a few megabytes.

## Dynamic Executable

```
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> ifort -O3 -qopenmp smt.f90 -o smt
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> size smt
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 748065   13984  296024 1058073  102519 smt
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> ldd smt
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002aaaaab0c000)
    libiomp5.so => /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.0.047/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.109/linux/compiler/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so (0x00002aaaaad86000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002aaaab0c7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaab2e4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /opt/gcc/5.1.0/snos/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002aaaab661000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002aaaab878000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)
```

## Dynamic Executable with Static Intel

```
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> ifort -O3 -qopenmp smt.f90 -static-intel -o smt
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> size smt
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1608953   41420  457016 2107389  2027fd smt
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> ls -l smt
-rwxr-x--- 1 jhammond jhammond 1872489 Jan 12 05:51 smt
```

## Static Executable

```
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> ifort -O3 -qopenmp smt.f90 -static -o smt
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> size smt
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
2262019   43120  487320 2792459  2a9c0b smt
jhammond@cori11:/tmp> ldd smt
    not a dynamic executable
```